# don't display chinese in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use google map api 3.9, in my application, the infowindow of poi has some english words, but in ditu.google.com, the infowindow display all chinese words, why?

my code is :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?v=3.9&libraries=geometry&sensor=false&language=zh-CN"></script>`

img1: http://nodeservice.com/nscloud/tmp/20131227152712.png

img2: http://nodeservice.com/nscloud/tmp/20131227152832.png

Comment: I want to display chinese.

Comment: Which image represents your desired output?

Comment: You're not actually using the 3.9 version of the API, despite what you've specified in your code.  The oldest currently available version is 3.13, which is what will be loaded in.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning for more information

Comment: The img2 is what I want. I can't get the result as img2 even I change my code to 3.13.